# dotnet restore failed: version conflicted. (.NET Core SDK 2.1.300)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I got this error by running dotnet restore in cmd

```
    $ dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassS     urvey1.csproj...
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (= 2.1.0) but version Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.1.2 was resolved. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions (= 2.1.0) but version Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.1.1 was resolved. [C:\     Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (= 2.1.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.4 was resolved. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (= 2.1.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.4 was resolved. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (= 2.1.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.4 was resolved. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : error NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.  [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : error NU1107:  ClassSurvey1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.1-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.1)  [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj : error NU1107:  ClassSurvey1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (= 2.1.0). [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]
  Restore failed in 692.51 ms for C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.csproj.
```

Here my version

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.300
 Commit:    adab45bf0c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

This project is the backend for my web app. The problem is I have zero knowledge about .NET. just try to follow the instructions from my friends which he claimed that it works on multiple pc (install .net sdk 2.1.300 and run dotnet restore)

What exactly do I need to install more?

Comment: .NET Core doesn't use the JDK ;P

Comment: I assume you mean .NET **S**DK?

Comment: Can you share the csproj file?

Comment: The error gives you the solution. Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.  [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ClassSurvey1\ClassSurvey1.sln]

Comment: But to the question: You most likely have the wrong (or outdated) version of the runtime installed (post result of `dotnet --list-runtimes` as well as check csproj if `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` has a `Version` attribute or not (if it has Verison attribute, remove it) also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: According to the errort,since you have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0`,try to reinstall above packages,and choose version to 2.1.0.

Comment: thanks guys. after config .csproj file i manage to restore.